# Visual Studio 2010 Global VC++ Directories Redux

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio-2010, build

I am going crazy trying to change the Global VC++ Directories under Visual Studio 2010. In particular the default Includes path.  I have read several articles on it, including [this one](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsproject/2009/07/07/vc-directories/), but can't seem to find where to change it.

Several articles say: "*Open View|Project Manager and edit the item in the tree called Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user*".  Only problem is that there is no **Project Manager** under the View menu nor any other menu item that I can see. At least not in VS 2010 SP1.

Below is what I see when I expand the View menu (I checked all the submenus as well).

Is there a version later than SP1 for VS 2010 C/CPP?  None that I can find.

[image]

Comment: Where, in the linked article, does it say to go to Project Manager? However, it does say "_if you bring up a VC++ project in the IDE and open the project properties window (right-click on the project node and select Properties), you will notice a Rule called VC++ Directories_" Did you try that?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I see how to change it for a specific project. But I am trying to change the global default Includes path for all projects (including future projects).  I must be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

The menu you are looking for is "View\Other Windows\Property Manager". "Property Manager" is in the view menu directly in newer versions of visual studio.

Comment: In older versions, you can add it there manually. Tools>Customize... , edit View Menu, add new command fron "Views" category, pick "Property Manager".

Comment: That allows me to change it for specific projects.  I am trying to change the global default Includes path for all projects (including future projects).

Comment: @NeilWeicher Did you read the blog post you linked? It explains exactly how to modify the global values.

Comment: @Alan, several times. Including [this one](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsproject/2009/06/23/inherited-properties-and-property-sheets/). Obviously I'm missing something that others are finding clear. Maybe time for another cup of coffee.

Comment: > If you open up the Property Manager view to see the property sheets associated with your project, you’ll see that one of the property sheets is named Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.User. This property sheet is actually stored in LocalAppData, just as VCComponents.dat file was, in the directory %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0. Using the property editor on the property sheet (just right-click on this property sheet node and select Properties…), you can see that you are able to make edits directly to this file. Since all projects, by default, import this property sheet, .....

Comment: There must be something wrong with my installation.  First I went to `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0`.  Pretty much empty. Nothing that looks like a Property Sheet.

Comment: Its not in that directory on my machine but it shouldn't matter where it is, just edit it in visual studio directly. you can see the full path in the properties window (not the properties pages, note the window is actually a dockable panel and the pages are a window, confused yet?) when the sheet is selected in the manager

Comment: @AlanBirtles. thanks for the answers  I took the easy way out and moved the projects to VS 2017 CPP.  I am easily able to do what I need there.